# Is there a graph theory textbook that covers treewidth thoroughly?

Tags: graphs, reference-request, treewidth

Can someone recommend a graph theory textbook that covers treewidth thoroughly?

Something that focuses on the graph-theoretic structure of bounded treewidth graphs rather than solving problems on them.  Don't need the strongest/newest results but would prefer something that

Preferably something that covers sublinear treewidth of planar and minor free graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the thing you are looking for exists, but here are at least some pointers:

[*Parameterized Algorithms* by Cygan *et al* (free PDF version)](http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl/parameterized-algorithms.pdf) has a chapter dedicated on the topic.  This is slightly algorithms oriented, but contains structural stuff too.

*Graph Theory* by Diestel has one chapter, (12.  Minors, Trees and WQO) on the subject, about 40 pages.  [homepage](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/)

Bodlaender has a chapter *Treewidth of Graphs* in the Encyclopedia of Algorithms.  [homepage](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4939-2864-4_431)

Heggernes has a short compendium used for her advanced algorithms class [Treewidth, partial $k$-trees, and chordal graphs](https://www.ii.uib.no/%7Epinar/chordal.pdf).

You also have Ton Kloks' book, Treewidth [springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540583561), but it's getting rather old.  I have not read this one, so I don't know much about it.